# Org-mode key bindings for emphasis markers (bold, italic, underline)

Tags: emacs, org-mode, key-bindings

I set `org-hide-emphasis-markers` to `true` in my init file, so that all text marked as ***bold*** just shows up as **bold**. But now I'm wondering how to toggle this formatting on/off without making these characters visible again... is there a key binding for this? How about italics and underline?

Thanks!

-Adam

Comment: I found this post: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10029/org-mode-how-to-create-an-org-mode-markup-keybinding but these key bindings only insert markup characters ** _ _ and //. I am looking for a key sequence so that I can place my curser over a word (or mark a region) and then toggle that work bold/unbold, underline/un-underline, italic/un-italic.

Comment: You can look at `org-fontify-emphasized-text` and `org-emphasis-alist`, but both of them can only be set at load time, so you can't use them to toggle things.

Comment: Hmm.. I am wondering what the intended workflow is when emphasis markers are hidden? For example, suppose you make a word bold by adding ** but then later you change your mind. How can you then go back to change this formatting without deleting the entire word or phrase or again turning off org-hide-emphasis-markers for the whole document..?

Comment: Org-mode just does the Right Thing.  It's only changing the display, not the underlying text.  Editing works as if it was e.g. fundamental-mode, so if you have `*bold*`, it's displayed as "**bold**", and you put point after the "d" and press backspace, it becomes `*bold` and is displayed as "*bold".

Comment: This works fine if `*bold*` is the last word in the sentence. But if you type `*bold* not bold, etc.`, placing the curser after "d" and hitting backspace does not reveal the formatting...

Comment: You're right, I should have played with it more.  I actually have `org-fontify-emphasized-text` set to `nil`, because I don't like it most of the time.  I really wish some of those settings were toggles or at least buffer local.

Comment: Hey, I found something that may be useful. Here is some code by John Kitchin that toggles latex previews off when the user mouses over the image. Maybe this can be adapted to display text only (i.e., "*bold*") when the user rolls over the fontified text...? Here is the link: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/10/09/Automatic-latex-image-toggling-when-cursor-is-on-a-fragment/ I'm a total eLisp nube. But I can give it a go, if nobody else wants to run with it...?

Answer (score 1):

[This is a workaround, not a solution]

If you place the cursor after the *bold* text and press `C-d`, the trailing asterisk is deleted and the leading markup becomes visible. Similarly, if you place the cursor before the bold text and press `C-d`, the leading asterisk is deleted and the trailing markup becomes visible.